# Android Studio cannot edit code in one android studio project window when a dialog window is open in some other android studio project window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

When I open multiple android studio windows for opening multiple android projects, I cannot edit or select or do anything in Window1 when there is a popup dialog open in window2. So I am downloading a SDK for Project2 then I cant even continue coding in Project1. How to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: It happens in other OS too. Like in Windows

Comment: So you mean it is what it is? There is no way we can solve this ?